# How to modify a tensor with a tensor of indices?

Tags: pytorch

I have a boolean tensor:

```
my_tensor = torch.tensor([[False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

I have a tensor of indices:

```
indices = torch.tensor([[0, 4],
        [0, 4]])
```

I want to modify `my_tensor` as:

```
my_tensor[indices] = True
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 2
```

The output should be

```
my_tensor = torch.tensor([[True, False, False, False, True],
        [True, False, False, False, True]])
```

It works with a 1D tensor:

```
my_tensor = torch.tensor([False, False, False, False, False])
indices = torch.tensor([0, 4])

my_tensor[indices] = True
my_tensor
>>> tensor([ True, False, False, False,  True])
```

Comment: Look at these link where they face the same problem: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/tensor-indexing-with-another-tensor/114485 There are some workarounds.